# Call function from class B in class A

Tags: php, class

I'm using PHP here, and I have two classes. Can I call a function from one class in the other one. For example:

```
class A
{
    function a_func()
    {
        echo "A function";
    }
}

$a = new A();

class B
{
    function b_func()
    {
        $a->a_func();    // This is the thing I'm stuck with.
    }
}
```

I hope I've made myself clear here. I had a look on Google, but I don't know what this is called so I came up with nothing. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 workarounds:
1) If your a_func doesn't need an instance (seems it's the case), you can make the function static and call it from the second class

```
class A
{
    public static function a_func()
    {
        echo "A function";
    }
}

class B
{
    function b_func()
    {
        A::a_func(); 
    }
}
```

2) 1) If your a_func needs an instance, you're forced to create one:

```
class A
{
    public function a_func()
    {
        echo "A function";
    }
}

class B
{
    function b_func()
    {
        $a = new A;
        $a->a_func();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to admit I'm pretty new to PHP classes. If I took this method, would I be able to access variables (via proxy functions) of the first instance of class A that I'd set earlier. The reason I'm asking the original question is because I have two objects, and I want to grab data from one, and use it in the other.

Comment: I've implemented the first of your solutions, and I've come up with this error: `Using $this when not in object context in envars.php`, with the line `echo A::a_func("argument");`. What's gone wrong here? I changed the functions to be `public static`, but still the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I should also add that the line in question is this: `$this->vars[$var]`. I'm really lost here, so any more help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty good answers so far. One thing that others have not mentioned yet...

If `B` requires an object `A` to work properly, you should pass one into the **constructor** and use [object composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition):

```
class B {

    protected $a;

    public function __construct(A $a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function b_func() {
        $this->a->a_func();
    }

}

$a = new A;
$b = new B($a);
$b->b_func();
```

You'll see that I've made the `$a` property in class `B` **protected**. This is for [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), definitely something you should read on.

Another important topic you should read on is [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you make `$a` local to `b_func()`.

Either by

- Declaring it `global $a;` inside `b_func()` (probably not a good idea, depends on your use case)
- passing `$a` as a parameter to `b_func()`:

  ```
  function b_func($a)
  ....
  ```
- making `$a` a member of `B`:

  ```
  $b = new B();
  $b->a = new a();  // Can be accessed by  `b_func()` as `$this->a`#
  ```
- or initializing `$a` inside `b_func()`:

  ```
  function b_func()
  {
    $a = new A();
  ```

which is the best in your scenario will depen on what A and B do, and what relation they have.

Comment: Thanks for this Pekka. I should have said this in my original question, but the original `$a` will be holding variables that I need to get the values of. I don't want to make another blank class, but call a function in the first object of type `$a` which will get a value I set earlier. Do I make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a_func() if you instantiate class A first:

```
class B
{
  function b_funct()
  {
    $a = new A(); //create instance of A
    $a->a_func(); //run function
  }
}
```

An alternative is make a_func static:

```
static function a_funct()
```

and call it as:

```
A::a_function();
```